# How to re-sync specific Gmail emails into Outlook 2010 using POP

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail, pop3

I haven't found anyone talking online about a very specific use-case I have concerning Gmail, and Outlook 2010.

I've made a backup of *almost* my entire Gmail account using Outlook 2010/POP3.

The problem is this: Not all the emails were imported. The first 6 months of my Gmail were never imported (stuff from way back in 2005/2006).

I'm aware that this is probably because back in 2005/6 I went into Gmail and turned on the "POP3: sync emails beginning now" feature in Gmail, so all prior emails aren't included in future email syncs using POP.  However, I'm worried that turning this feature off in Gmail (is that possible, to roll that back?) would reset the POP record on Gmail's server, and when I sync the thing will re-download every email from scratch, giving me thousands of duplicates.

What's the best way to import a block of emails from Gmail, but not the entire thing? Are there any tools available or Outlook addons to do this? I'm stuck.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also configure your GMAIL account as an IMAP (temporarily) within your Outlook. Do a custom search for the time range that you're missing emails from in the IMAP account. Then select those emails and copy them (Holding CTRL when dragging) up to your POP account. Once you have copied the missing emails from your IMAP account, remove the account and continue with your POP.

You are correct, if you flag it to redownload all mails, it will create duplicates.

Comment: You are a lifesaver - great idea!!